# Fail when Extending Python with C++

Tags: c++, python-3.7, visual-studio-2019, pybind11

With the recommendation of pybind11, I am trying to call python libs in my C++ program these days(**Ultimate goal： use pickle to read data in python, and pass them to C++**). I used Visual Studio 2019 and python3.7(Anaconda Version) to do this job. 
Following the tutorial in [pybind11 Doc](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/advanced/pycpp/object.html), I practiced the simplest demo like that:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "python37.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "python3.lib")

#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

using namespace std;

namespace py = pybind11;


int main()
{

    py::object Decimal = py::module::import("decimal").attr("Decimal");

}
```

But the VS2019 told me this:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA9A5384E7 (python37.dll) in hello_Call_py_From_C.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000025.
```

The include and lib directories I used are :

```
Anaconda3\include, pybind11\include;
Anaconda3\libs;
```

When I continued to debug,  it told me "unicodeobject.c not found", like this:
[image]

To make it clear, I searched the derecotories in my PC, and all the 'unicodeobject' is '.h' rather than '.c', which are mostly in the Anaconda Folder rather than pybind11:
[image]

I continued to check if decimal is not a illegal pac in python, but in fact it is:
[image]

So I am more puzzled and don't know who to be blamed. 
What't more, I would also appreciate if you can guide me to another wiser way to tackle this task.
Thank you!

Comment: `Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000025` implies a nul pointer dereference, have you tried debugging?

Comment: @ZimengZhao: It looks like unicodeobject.c is part of pybind11. That's unlikely to be the direct cause of your crash - it's just that Visual Studio doesn't have the source code available.

Comment: i'd guess that `py::module::import("decimal")` failed.

Comment: @Thomas :I continued to check if decimal is not a illegal pac in python, but in fact it is. Is this your concern ?

Comment: @Alan Birtles : Yeah, when I continued to debug, it told me "unicodeobject.c not found". Is it the debug info you imply?

Comment: [this](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/object.html#accessing-python-libraries-from-c) states 'available in the current Python environment', so I'd guess that is the problem or not compatible.

Comment: @ Thomas：Thank you, but I think the default env should be the program chooses, for the include and lib directories are consistent with the Anaconda default.

Comment: Is hello_Call_py_From_C.exe the executable you generate, from this code?

Comment: @Uninitialized: yeah, it is